# Selenium scrape with full xpath and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to get the Nasdaq "Most Advanced" list of stocks from here: http://www.nasdaq.com/extended-trading/premarket-mostactive.aspx (click on Most Advanced tab)

What is the best way using Selenium to loop through all the Symbols and put them into a Python list?  I have figured out the XPATH to the first Symbol:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[7]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/h3/a
```

but am not sure where to go from there.. I tried:

```
element=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[7]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/h3/a")
print element.text
```

..as a start just to see if I can get a value but it obviously doesn't work.  Sorry for the stupid question :(

Comment: Did you ever figure out the correct syntax for using the full xpath? If so, I'd be interested to learn what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

These xpaths containing the full absolute path to the element are very fragile.

Rely on the class name (`//div[@class="symbol_links"]`):

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver


driver = webdriver.WebDriver()
driver.get('http://www.nasdaq.com/extended-trading/premarket-mostactive.aspx')

# choose "Most Advanced" tab
advanced_link = driver.find_element_by_id('most-advanced')
advanced_link.click()

# get the symbols
print [symbol.text for symbol in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="symbol_links"]') if symbol.text]

driver.close()
```

prints:

```
[u'RNA', u'UBIC', u'GURE', u'DRTX', u'DSLV', u'YNDX', u'QIWI', u'NXPI', u'QGEN', u'ZGNX']
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  But that gets me the Most Active list, not the Most Advanced list.. which also uses the symbol_links class but doesn't seem to show up even though its included in the same page source.  Ideas?

Comment: @peelers just click on Most Advanced tab before getting symbols.

Comment: Hmm.. finding the element by ID didn't work for me, not sure why.. very strange.  driver.execute_script("current('most-advanced')") worked though.  Thanks again!